# How can I collect information on a background page in a Google Chrome extension, and display that information in the popup?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that collects and stores the url and timestamp of every visit to a Stack Overflow page in an array in [Chrome storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage). I am collecting this data in a (persistent) background page, and I would like for my popup to display the latest visits.

I am new to web programming, so maybe I'm missing something, but I can't get my popup to display anything besides the text I directly typed into the html. Here is the relevant part of my background page:

**background.js**

```
// Store url in chrome storage and filter by url host suffix
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(details) {
  // 0 indicates the navigation happens in the tab content window
  if (details.frameId === 0) {
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // create visit object containing tabUrl and timestamp
        var tabUrl = tabs[0].url;
        var timestamp = new Date();
        var visit = {};
        visit[timestamp] = tabUrl;

        // get visitlist if it exists, otherwise initialize to empty list
        chrome.storage.local.get({'visitList': []}, function(item) {
          var newVisitList = item.visitList;
          if (newVisitList.indexOf(visit) === -1) {
            newVisitList.push(visit);
          }
          chrome.storage.local.set({visitList: newVisitList});
        })
      })
  }
}, {url: [{hostSuffix : 'stackoverflow.com'}]});
```

In my popup.js, I am trying to retrieve the latest url and timestamp variables from Chrome Storage. This is a bit tricky since I am storing an array of visit {timestamp:url} objects.

**popup.js**

```
function displayVisit () {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['visitList'], function(list){
      var visitList = result.visitList;
      var latestVisit = {};
      latestVisit = visitList.pop();

      var timestamp = latestVisit.key;
      var url = latestVisit[timestamp];

      visitList.push(latestVisit);

      $('#timestamp').text(timestamp);
      $('#url').text(url);
  });
}
```

In my popup.html, I am simply trying to display the last visited StackOverflow url and timestamp, but the variables do not show up on the popup.

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Stack Overflow Visit History</title>
  <style>body {min-width: 150px;}</style>
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>StackOverflow Recent Visits</h1>
  <h2>Url: <span id="url"></span></h2>
  <h2>Time: <span id="timestamp"></span></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

And this my manifest if that provides any helpful context:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Stack Overflow visit history",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This Chrome extension stores your Stack Overflow URL visits and provides statistics.",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "16": "icon16.png"
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "StackOverflowVisits"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "declarativeContent",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/*"
  ]
}
```

Am I not using Chrome storage correctly, or is the problem in the way I'm trying to access the variables in my popup?

Comment: 1) Remove `chrome.tabs.query` call - it's incorrect here because the navigated tab may not be the active one - and simply use `details.url`, see the documentation for webNavigation for more info. 2) Remove background.js from popup.html. The background script runs in a separate hidden background page, not related to the popup page. 3) Switch `page_action` to `browser_action`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I followed your advice and cleaned up my code a bit and now it's working! I had thought that my extension should be a page action since it only collects StackOverflow urls, but I understand now why it should be a browser action (since you want to be able to access the popup at any time).